# Forecasting time series data using EEMD based SVM?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, svm, supervised-learning, ensemble-learning

**Splitting of Dataset:**
Dataset = Train1 + Test1
EEMD(Train1) = train1 + test1

---

I am forecasting on time series data("Dataset") using *SVM*. First I found the **Intrinic Mode Function(IMF)** of time series data (training dataset, *Train1*) using **Ensemble Empirical Mode Decomposition (EEMD)**.Let's say I got 8 IMF (including resudial).  Test dataset(*Test1*) is kept apart for only testing with final prediction.

Now I divided each IMFs into training(*train1*) and testing dataset(*test1*). Then trained 8 different SVM (SVR) model (8 IMFs and 8 SVR model) using sklearn (as it is shown in image - *step 2*)

Then forecasted as many data points as the number of elements in test dataset (Test1) using corresponding SVR model and IMF dataset (train1) on which it was trained. So now I have forecasted on each IMF. Step 2 is complete.

---

**For step 3, I am confused.**

**Confusion 1:** What dataset(either Train1 or train1) should I use for training the SVM in step 3? Or Should I use one of the 8 (already) trained model from step 2.

**Confusion 2:** It is written following for doing step 3 in the [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5534762)-

> Use SVM to combine the prediction result of each IMF and residual
>   component and generate an aggregated result as the final prediction of
>   the original time series

**How can I "combine" using SVM here?** Does it mean to use forecasted data from step 2 as 8 input features (X) for SVM in step 3? **What should be input(X) and target(y)  for training SVM in step 3.** *I have never done ensembling before.*

---

Following is the screenshots from the paper:

[image]

[image]

[image]